# Collect rows into a single row if Name-row is empty CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file that has several columns. Two of the columns are called Namn (Name) (Product) and Alla bilder (All images).
Some of the products have several images. These images are inserted on their own row under the "All images":
Example:

Name       All images 
Name1       Image1
Name2       Image2
                      Image2-1
                      Image2-2
Name3       Image3

I am trying to get all images belonging to one product to be inserted in the first image-row and seperated by a |. Here's the code I've managed with help from a friend to make, but I just don't get it to work. (I downloaded Python, and ran the .py script) - Nothing happens. Please note I have never touched Python before.

```
import codecs, csv

def main():

    file_input = codecs.open('test.csv', 'r', 'utf-8-sig')
    dictreader = csv.DictReader(file_input, delimiter=',')

    main_rows = []
    fields = []
    temp_row = {}

    for row_item in dictreader:

        if len(fields) == 0:
            # fix the fields header...
            for field in row_item:
                fields.append(field)

        if row_item['Name'] == '':
            # this row probably only contains picture information...
            if 'Alla bilder' in row_item and row_item['Alla bilder'] != '':
                if 'Alla bilder' not in temp_row:
                    temp_row['Alla bilder'] = row_item['Alla bilder']
                elif temp_row['Alla bilder'] == '':
                    temp_row['Alla bilder'] = row_item['Alla bilder']
                else:
                    temp_row['Alla bilder'] = temp_row['Alla bilder'] + '|' + row_item['Alla bilder']
        else:
            # this seems to be a new product row...

            if len(temp_row) != 0:
                # there seems to be something to store....
                print('\nSTORING: ' + str(temp_row))
                main_rows.append(temp_row)
                temp_row = {}

            # print('\nNEW ROW: ' + str(row_item))
            temp_row = row_item

    if len(temp_row) != 0:
        # there seems to be something to store....
        print('\nSTORING: ' + str(temp_row))
        main_rows.append(temp_row)

    file_output = codecs.open('test2.csv', 'w', 'utf-8-sig')
    dictwriter = csv.DictWriter(file_output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fields)
    dictwriter.writerows(main_rows)


if _name_ == "_main_":
    main()
else:
    print('This file was called from another class...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error or message gives you when you start the script from the console?

Try changing

```
if _name_ == "_main_":
   main()
else:
   print('This file was called from another class...')
```

For

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
else:
   print('This file was called from another class...')
```

It's the only error I see (if I'm not wrong, it's `__name__`, not `_name_`). Changing that works for me. Using this input:

```
Name,Alla bilder
Name1,Image1
Name2,Image2
,Image2-1
,Image2-2
Name3,Image3
```

I get the next result:

```
Name1,Image1
Name2,Image2|Image2-1|Image2-2
Name3,Image3
```

Is that your problem?